# Knife command to check last node check-ins?

Tags: chef, knife

Is there a `knife` incantation that allows me to check the Last Check-In time of given (or all) nodes in my environment.  (As opposed to the http:///status page in Open-Source Chef.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does `knife status` not work?

```
$ knife status
24 minutes ago, server-063.vm.example.com, server-063.vm.example.com, 192.168.1.188, ubuntu 10.04.
4 minutes ago, server-061.vm.example.com, server-061.vm.example.com, 192.168.1.184, ubuntu 10.04.
3 minutes ago, server-062.vm.example.com, server-062.vm.example.com, 192.168.1.39, ubuntu 10.04.
```

Comment: facepalm.  You win!

Comment: note that the "time ago" is reflected by the last time the node successfully saved at the end of a chef client run. It does not report if the node had an unsuccessful chef run. Opscode is working on a reporting framework for the commercial products for this, and you can use the Report/Exception handler feature to send failed runs to another service such as email, hoptoad or others.